# Applying a Mask to a Video Preview on Android

Tags: android, video, surfaceview, mask

I'm trying to apply a mask on a video feed (preview) on Android.

The idea is to crop out the video on the device screen, making it look circular.

Here's what I've been able to accomplish so far:

[image: scren grab of app]

(ignore the black circular band inside the video feed, that is a separate asset in the xml layout)

As you can see, I've got the video, with a circular hole in the middle.  I need the opposite (i.e. I should see the video inside the "hole", and the rest should be invisible).

I'm overriding my SurfaceView's draw method and applying a Porter-Duff Mode:

Here's the relevant code:

```
package org.dornad.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private Camera camera;
    private final SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Bitmap rounderBitmap;
    private Paint xferPaint;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);

        this.camera = camera;
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        Bitmap currentBitmap = get();
        int w = currentBitmap.getWidth(), h = currentBitmap.getHeight();

        if (rounderBitmap == null) 
            rounderBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(rounderBitmap);

        if (xferPaint == null)  
            xferPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        xferPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

        c.drawCircle(w/2, h/2, 100, xferPaint);
        xferPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

        canvas.drawBitmap(currentBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(rounderBitmap, 0, 0, xferPaint);
    }

    private Bitmap get() {
        return this.getDrawingCache();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            setWillNotDraw(false);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            L.d("Error setting camera preview : %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (holder.getSurface() == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop an non-existent preview
        }

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            L.d("Error setting camera preview : %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty.  Take care of releasing the Camera preview in the Activity/Fragment.
    }
}
```

According to a visual guide of the Porter-Duff blending modes:

[image: XferModes Example]

What I'm looking for should be PorterDuff.Mode.XOR, but what I get instead is the circle with a red filling, instead of the video feed.  (I'm aware that the red comes from the xferPaint.setColor call)

Any ideas?

Comment: So the camera is sending frames to the Surface, and you're also drawing on the Surface?  My expectation is that, once you've drawn on it once, you'll never see camera output again.  Do you see any complaints in logcat?

Comment: I'll take a look at the logcat as soon as I'm back in the office.  But AFAIK (or remember) there were no complaints.

Comment: Just checked.  There are no complaints on logcat.

Comment: I think I read your code wrong... you're sending frames to the Surface, and rendering into the View (which is normally just a transparent "hole").  The blending between the View and the Surface will be done by the system compositor, so the app rendering doesn't have any prior contents to blend with.  Select a mode where you're setting the alpha in the output pixels to be transparent or opaque as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `xferPaint` for two things:

- to draw a circle in a buffer
- to draw the buffer on top of the preview

and you're re-drawing the circle on every render into `rounderBitmap` with `DST_IN`!

I think if you reorder your code you may get the wanted result (not tested):

```
    Bitmap currentBitmap = get();
    int w = currentBitmap.getWidth(), h = currentBitmap.getHeight();

    if (rounderBitmap == null) {
        rounderBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(rounderBitmap);
        Paint holePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        holePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        c.drawCircle(w / 2, h / 2, 100, holePaint);
    }

    if (xferPaint == null) {
        Paint xferPaint = new Paint();
        xferPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(currentBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(rounderBitmap, 0, 0, xferPaint);
```

Also you if it works then you may want to consider:

- allocate `rounderBitmap` as a `200x200` bitmap, instead of `w x h`
- `drawCircle(100, 100, 100`
- position `rounderBitmap` at `w/2-100`, `h/2-100` when `drawBitmap`.

In general, you can try dumping the bitmap to see if it is what you want it to be (image with a circle in the middle (with correct colors/alpha):

```
static int counter;
// inside draw:
File out = new File(getContext().getExternalCacheDir(), "frame_"+ counter++ +".png");
Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, new FileOutputStream(out));
Log.d("DEBUG", "Written: " + out);
```

*Disclaimer: I don't have experience with PorterDuff, all the above is just general advice.*